# Firestore Emulator not showing data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

i'm trying to connect my emulator firestore database with my webapp. What's weird is that i'm able to use the emulator auth and emulator storage to create user and upload files respectively but when i try push data up to firestore emulator nothing happens as in nothing shows in the emulator and i get no errors when i execute the code.

I am able to see `Requests` as below but nothing in `Data` in the emulator.
[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Add more code snippets

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { connectAuthEmulator, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { connectFunctionsEmulator, getFunctions } from "firebase/functions";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
require("firebase/storage");
import { getStorage, connectStorageEmulator } from "firebase/storage";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

const hostname = window.location.hostname;
console.log("hostname: ", hostname);
const app =
  hostname === "localhost"
    ? initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_DEMOSTORAGEBUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
        // measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
      })
    : initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
        measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
      });

// REACT_APP_DEMOSTORAGEBUCKET

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const functions = getFunctions(app);
export const analytics = () => {
  if (hostname === "localhost") {
    return;
  } else {
    return getAnalytics(app);
  }
};

if (hostname === "localhost") {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
}
```

The details used for the emulator are essentially the same as that for the live environment, the difference is just starting things up with `firebase emulators:start --project=demo-project`. And i use a live but different storage bucket so that a 3rd party can access my images. All these setting i've used in the past have worked, the exception is recently when i try to view firestore data.

Comment: Please include relevant code snippets - these should always be included in any question. It's likely you have a project ID mismatch between your app config and the project ID you start the emulators with (ie `demo-project`)

Answer (score 0):

A few things before we arrive at your possible problem. Make sure all your providers are configured and uncommented (`app module`) Then, you need to run:

```
$ firebase emulators:start
```

Once you stop running your emulator, the data disappear because *the data lives locally in memory.*
Now, if you want to preserve your data when you start again, you need to export it. So, while your emulator is running do the following:

```
$ firebase emulators:export my-test-data
```

This will create `xml` files containing all the data exported, *so later when we start the emulator we could use it again*. It will also create `my-test-data` folder.
Now, to use the data run:

```
$ firebase emulators:start --import my-test-data
```

At this point the data should be available for your dev environment. Now you should see your data. I hope it helps!

Comment: I typically don't export or import my data when using emulators. I start the emulators with ```firebase emulators:start --project=demo-project```

Comment: In that case, when working with demo Firebase projects, your apps and code interact with emulators only. If your app attempts to interact with a resource for which an emulator isn't running, that code will fail.

Comment: i remember reading this someone in the documentation. Like if i try running firestore and there isn't a firestore resource running it will fail?

Comment: Not just the firestore... it could be another resource. Try running just the following:  
`$ firebase emulators:start --only firestore --project=demo-project`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that Firestore client tries to access a database at the Firebase projectId `process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID`. Therefore the emulator UI and the client are working on different Firestore databases.

Instead, you will need to pass the demo project id when calling `initializeApp()` for the client to access the demo project's Firestore database.

Based on your code, that would look something like this with `demo-X` being the demo project id:

```
const app =
  hostname === "localhost"
    ? initializeApp({
        apiKey: "demo-key",
        authDomain: "demo-X.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "demo-X",
        storageBucket: "demo-X.appspot.com",
        appId: "demo-appId",
      })
    : initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
        measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

had exactly the same problem you have and I got it fixed

The problem is that the projectId in my client application was not the same given in the `firebase emulator:start` command

When initializing the firebase app from my client I would do it like this
(I am using flutter, so this will be Dart code but the foundation is the same)

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  Config(environment: Environment.dev);

  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  const host = 'myIpHere';

  FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator(host, 8080, sslEnabled: false);
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator(host, 9099);
  await FirebaseStorage.instance.useStorageEmulator(host, 9199);
  FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: Config.functionsRegion).useFunctionsEmulator(host, 5001);

  runApp(const Entry());
}
```

Where `DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform` is:

```dart
static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
  apiKey: 'someKeyHere',
  appId: 'someIdHere',
  messagingSenderId: 'someOtherId',
  projectId: 'project-XYZ',
  storageBucket: 'moreStuff',
);
```

So, my projectId in my client had value of `project-XYZ`

But in my firebase emulator I was starting it with this command:
`firebase emulators:start --project project-X`

And thanks to that I was not seeing the data in firestore but I was able to see the requests just like you did

Once I put corrected the project IDs it all started working fine

Hope it helps!